# How can I get the file field uploaded file path of a node?

Tags: nodes, uri, files

I am using the tpl file to creat a node page to contain the video player, JW player. I have created 2 content types,in one of it , I build a file field to upload the video, another file field to upload the srt file. How can I get the path of these file fields and use it as  dynamic url in the JW player?

Comment: Why can't you simply use [JW Player module for Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/jw_player)? It already takes care of all the things you seem to try to achieve here.

Comment: I have used JW Player module,and it works well,but I need to add the other function to the player,such as different quality,closed caption,and chapters,etc. So I need to creat the node.tpl file to get there.